# How to generate strings drawn from every possible character?

Tags: haskell, generator, quickcheck

At the moment I'm generating strings like this:

```
arbStr :: Gen String
arbStr = listOf $ elements (alpha ++ digits)
  where alpha = ['a'..'z']
        digits = ['0'..'9']
```

But obviously this only generates strings from alpha num chars. How can I do it to generate from all possible chars?

Comment: `Char` is already an `Arbitrary` instance, so you can just the the `arbitrary` method for that. If you need a `String`, you could also use the `String` instance, which is available via that `[]` instance.

Comment: Could you give an example how to do that? I'm a bit stuck on how the code would look like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Char` is a instance of both the `Enum` and `Bounded` typeclass, you can make use of the [**`arbitraryBoundedEnum :: (Bounded a, Enum a) => Gen a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.13.2/docs/Test-QuickCheck.html#v:arbitraryBoundedEnum) function:

```
import Test.QuickCheck(Gen, arbitraryBoundedEnum, listOf)

arbStr :: Gen String
arbStr = listOf arbitraryBoundedEnum
```

For example:

```
Prelude Test.QuickCheck> sample arbStr
""
""
"\821749"
"\433465\930384\375110\256215\894544"
"\431263\866378\313505\1069229\238290\882442"
""
"\126116\518750\861881\340014\42369\89768\1017349\590547\331782\974313\582098"
"\426281"
"\799929\592960\724287\1032975\364929\721969\560296\994687\762805\1070924\537634\492995\1079045\1079821"
"\496024\32639\969438\322614\332989\512797\447233\655608\278184\590725\102710\925060\74864\854859\312624\1087010\12444\251595"
"\682370\1089979\391815"
```

Or you can make use of the `arbitrary` in the `Arbitrary Char` typeclass:

```
import Test.QuickCheck(Gen, arbitrary, listOf)

arbStr :: Gen String
arbStr = listOf arbitrary
```

Note that the `arbitrary` for `Char` is implemented such that ASCII characters are (three times) more common than non-ASCII characters, so the "distribution" is different.

Comment: Why does the first example only return slashes and numbers? Or are those ASCII numbers?

Comment: @doctopus: these are just characters in the unicode range. Since it picks characters *uniformly*, 0.2% of the characters picked will be ASCII, since the number of non-ASCIIs is simply huge. That is why you might want to use `arbitrary` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Since Char is an instance of Bounded as well as Enum (confirm this by asking GHCI for `:i Char`), you can simply write

```
[minBound..maxBound] :: [Char]
```

to get a list of all legal characters. Obviously this will not lead to efficient random access, though! So you could instead convert the bounds to `Int` with `Data.Char.ord :: Char -> Int`, and use QuickCheck's feature to select from a range of integers, then map back to a character with `Data.Chra.chr :: Int -> Char`.

Answer (score 1):

When we do like

```
λ> length ([minBound..maxBound] :: [Char])
1114112
```

we get the number of all characters and say Wow..! If you think the list is too big then you may always do like `drop x . take y` to limit the range.

Accordingly, if you need `n` many random characters just [`shuffle :: [a] -> IO [a]`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/232894/105433) the list and do a `take n` from that shuffled list.

**Edit:**

Well of course... since shuffling could be expensive, it's best if we chose a clever strategy. It would be ideal to *randomly* limit the all characters list. So just

1. make a `limits = liftM sort . mapM randomRIO $ replicate 2 (0,1114112) :: (Ord a, Random a, Num a) => IO [a]`
2. `limits >>= \[min,max] -> return . drop min . take max $ ([minBound..maxBound] :: [Char])`
3. Finally just take `n` many like random `Char`s like `liftM . take n` from the result of **Item 2**.